# How do I change my app's Bundle ID for an Existing App on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

What is the easiest way to change the Bundle ID for an Existing App that is already posted on the App Store?  I want to preserve everything else including the App's name and only change the Bundle ID.

A related question is: what are the implications of having the wrong Bundle ID for an existing app on the App Store?  The reason I ask is: The developer of this app chose an arbitrary Bundle ID that is unrelated to our domain name.  Should we resubmit the app with the correct Bundle ID using our domain name?  And if so, do we really need to delete the App with the wrong Bundle ID or can we simply submit the app with right Bundle ID to replace it?

Comment: Probably better asked elsewhere, but if I were advising you I would not change the bundle ID even if possible once an app's on the store. It's not likely to ever matter, and if it's arbitrary it probably won't collide with anything. There's no "wrong" bundle ID. Users never see it.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ben.  Where else should I post this question?  Should I add different tags?

Comment: @Ben: the arbitrary Bundle ID is on a made up domain name that is registered to someone else.  Can the owner of that domain insist on us changing our Bundle ID?  And if we had to do, would we have to delete the app from the App store and start all over just to change the Bundle ID?

Comment: I would ask at the Apple dev forums (and this may even be a rare occasion where it is worth contacting Apple developer support for your peace of mind if you can't find a technical answer anywhere). But that said, the owner of the other domain is unlikely to even be able to know, much less care or attempt to insist that you change anything. (You don't have to own a domain to use it in a bundle ID, although of course that's standard.) I don't know the process for changing a bundle ID. It may be trivial or not possible; I just don't know.